Function overloading depending on compile-time object state
Consider having a simple class, that writes integers to cout depending on its state:
#include <iostream>

class NotAWriter{
public:
    NotAWriter& operator<<(const int& arg) {
        if (on) std::cout << arg;
        return *this;
    }
    void toggle() {on=!on;}
private:
    bool on = false;
};

Consider now I have a COMPILE-TIME constant number of toggles (i.e. calls to NotAWriter.toggle()).
I want a program to choose whether to print or not depending on the variable on in compile-time, something like this:
NotAWriter& operator<<(const int& arg) {
    if constexpr (on) std::cout << arg;
    return *this;
}

or this
std::enable_if<on, NotAWriter&> operator<<(const int& arg) {
    std::cout << arg;
    return *this;
}
std::enable_if<!on, NotAWriter&> operator<<(const int& arg) {return *this;}

However the usage of this in constant expressions is prohibited:
error: use of ‘this’ in a constant expression
  |      if constexpr (on) std::cout << arg;
  |      ^~

Is there a way to do this (choose overload or if-branch) depending on a member-variable at compile-time? If I sure the number of variable changes is compile-time constant, of course.

Stateful template metaprogramming is a thing. Albeit a very complicated and hacky thing. It crept into the language by accident

Is it possible? Quite likely, templates are Turing-complete. Are your coworkers going to throw you out of the window for pushing such code to review and trying to get them to read it? Definitely. It's going to be a horrible mess.

"If I sure the number of variable changes is compile-time constant" -- Could you provide an example of this? Say something with 3 changes, so people can verify that this sequence of changes actually falls under "compile-time" (and possibly to spark inspiration for a solution).

If you know the number and value of each toggle at compile time, why not just write a variadic non-type template Writer<true,false,true,...> or whatever? Then the operator can just fold || over the pack and you're not using a runtime data member to store static state

There is no such thing as "compile-time constant number of changes".

@n.m.couldbeanAI search for "Stateful metaprogramming"

Stateful metaprogramming is a misnomer (the same name can mean different things in different contexts, big deal), it doesn't work reliably across compilers, it can be outlawed in a future version of C++, and last bit not least, it cannot count changes, only count occurrences of some construct (like template instantiation). So yeah. If none of this matters, you can do that.

Is there a reason you can't rely on something like this or similar:
#include <iostream>

template <bool on>
class NotAWriter
{
public:
    NotAWriter& operator<<(const int& arg)
    {
        if constexpr (on)
            std::cout << arg;
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    NotAWriter<false>() << 4;
    NotAWriter<true>() << 4;
    return 0;
}


In fact I need to choose overloading depending on a number of operator<< calls. So numbering of every call will be a hard-routine. Here I just have oversimplified the dependence on int to the dependence on bool without losing the main point. But your example will be useful in some other cases, thanks!

@MPEI_stud Ok, a bit unclear what your needs are though keep in mind you can adjust it to this instead of it helps template <typename U> NotAWriter& operator<<(const U& arg)

Maybe template <bool on> NotAWriter<!on> NotAWriter<on>::toggle() { return {}; } might help...

Here are various examples of stateful metaprogramming such as compile-time counters, lists, etc...
So using compile time counter my example can be done as following (in this example operator<< call write numbers once in a while)
#include <iostream>

// Code from site mentioned above
template<unsigned N>
struct reader {
    friend auto counted_flag(reader<N>);
};

template<unsigned N>
struct setter {
    friend auto counted_flag(reader<N>) {}

    static constexpr unsigned n = N;
};

template<auto Tag, unsigned NextVal = 0>
[[nodiscard]]
consteval auto counter_impl() {
    constexpr bool counted_past_value = requires(reader<NextVal> r) {
        counted_flag(r);
    };

    if constexpr (counted_past_value) {
        return counter_impl<Tag, NextVal + 1>();
    } else {
        setter<NextVal> s;
        return s.n;
    }
}


template<auto Tag = []{}, auto Val = counter_impl<Tag>()>
constexpr auto counter = Val;
// Code from site mentioned above

class NotAWriter{
public:

    template<typename std::enable_if_t<counter<> % 2 != 0, bool> = true>
    NotAWriter& operator<<(const int& arg) {
        std::cout << arg;
        return *this;
    }

    template<typename std::enable_if_t<counter<> % 2 == 0, bool> = true>
    NotAWriter& operator<<(const int& arg) {return *this;}

};

int main(){
    NotAWriter writer;
    writer << 43433 << 9932 << 12032; // Only 9932 is actually printer
}


So you never actually wanted the explicit toggle from your question?

This doesn't compile with any compiler I've tried.

@n.m.couldbeanAI: With some modifications, I succeeded to work as intended Demo, but only for gcc, not clang

@Jarod42 Yes clang either doesn't work or works not as intended with a lot of stateful metaprogramming code that gcc and msvc accept.

"my example can be done as following" -- I don't see an example in the question. Nor do I see any use of toggle in this answer. It's a bit hard to tell if this answers what was actually asked (rather than what you think you asked).
